# grepで[こ]んな感じに1文字だけ角括弧で囲う意味は何ですか？

Tags: shellscript, grep

他の人が、次のように1文字だけ角括弧で囲んで grep コマンドを実行しているのを見ました。

```sh
ps -ax | grep [e]macs
```

単に `grep emacs` と実行するのとどう違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[こ]のように書くことで、`grep` プロセス自身が検索にひっかからなくなります。

`grep` は正規表現をサポートしているので、角括弧を使ってたとえば `[abc]macs` と書くと `amacs`, `bmacs`, `cmacs` にマッチします。今回のように1文字だけ指定して `[e]macs` と書くと、マッチとしては `emacs` と書くのと同じ動作をします。

ところでこの正規表現は `grep` が解釈するものでシェルが解釈するものではないので、`ps -ax` の出力にも `[e]macs` と表示されます。したがってこれ自体は `[e]macs` というパターンにマッチしません。

このため、`[e]macs` をパターンとして使うと検索を実行している `grep` プロセス自体が表示されなくなり、紛らわしさが減ります。

```sh
$ ps -ax | grep emacs
  154 ?        Ss     0:00 emacs --daemon
 5502 tty1     R      0:00 grep --color=auto emacs
$ ps -ax | grep [e]macs
  154 ?        Ss     0:00 emacs --daemon
```

Comment: `pgrep` も使えますよね。あと `ps | grep emacs | grep -v grep` なんてのもやりますけどいささか冗長

Comment: @774RR さん、なるほどそういうコマンドもあるのですね！　問題の捉え方を変えた別質問を投稿してみましたので、もしよろしければ回答として投稿いただけませんでしょうか？　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/55386/19110